# Archive template limiting to 4 entries?

Tags: templates, archives

I have a category called "javascript" and it's limiting my list to only 4 entries?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="decorate">
        <h1>Javascript</h1>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

          <?php endwhile; ?>

          <?php endif; ?>
          </div><!-- end decorate -->
      </div><!-- end row -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The link to this page is:

```
<li><a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/category/javascript">Javascript</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the loop in the template file.

Check Settings>>Reading>>"Blog pages show at most..."

That setting is the default setting for Archives, too, as well as Search results, etc.

Use [WordPress › Custom Post Limits « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-limits/) to vary posts limits in categories, archives, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=-1')
```

Add it right before `if(have_posts())...` and add `wp_reset_query();` after the loop ends.